# How can aggregate lines in CSV based on value of one column

Tags: shell-script, awk, csv-simple

My input is the following sorted CSV file (using `:` as the field delimiter instead of the usual comma):

```
version:device
1.0.0:dev1
1.0.0:dev2
1.2.3:dev3
1.3.4:dev4
1.3.4:dev5
```

I want to aggregate it so that each version is in 1 line:

```
version:devices
1.0.0:dev1,dev2
1.2.3:dev3
1.3.4:dev4,dev5
```

Comment: The meaning of "sorted" is somewhat ambiguous in your question. Is the file sorted according to `version`, or according to `device` (i.e. can the same value for `version` only appear in consecutive lines, or can a previously encountered value re-appear after lines with different `version`)?

Comment: Looks like most solutions are missing the required change from `device` to `devices` in the first line of output.

Comment: The headers are not really in the file, I just added it for readablility

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using GNU `datamash` to group by the first colon-separated field, collapsing the second field:

```bash
$ datamash -t : groupby 1 collapse 2 <file
version:device
1.0.0:dev1,dev2
1.2.3:dev3
1.3.4:dev4,dev5
```

Answer (score 2):

[miller](/questions/tagged/miller) is a pretty amazing tool:

```bash
mlr --csv --fs : group-by version then nest --ivar , -f device file.csv
```

```
version:device
1.0.0:dev1,dev2
1.2.3:dev3
1.3.4:dev4,dev5
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
awk -F: '$1 == before { printf ",%s",$2 ; } 
         $1 != before { printf "%s%s",nl,$0 ; before=$1 ; nl="\n" } 
         END {printf nl ; }'
```

where

- `-F:` tell awk to use `:` as separator
- `printf` do not print newline, unless tol (`"\n"`)
- this can be onelined (e.g.`awk -F: '....' file`), I split line for readability.

this use two variables to hold new line (`nl`) and previous `$1`'s value.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do what you want.

```
awk -F':' 'OFS=""; NR == 1; NR > 1 {x=$1;$1="";a[x]=a[x]$0","}END{for(x in a)print x":"a[x]}' file
```

Comment: This will not output the columns in the same order as in the input file.

Answer (score 0):

```c
awk -F: -v OFS=: '
    NR == 1{print;next} 
    !v {v=$1;d=$2;next} 
    v == $1 {d = d","$2}
    v != $1 {print v,d;v=$1;d=$2}
    END{print v,d}
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS=":" }
$1 != prev {
    if ( NR == 1 ) {
        devs = $2 "s"
    }
    else {
        print prev, devs
        devs = $2
    }
    prev = $1
    next
}
{ devs = devs "," $2 }
END { print prev, devs }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
version:devices
1.0.0:dev1,dev2
1.2.3:dev3
1.3.4:dev4,dev5
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution with csvkit:

```
csvsql -d ':' --query \
    'SELECT version, GROUP_CONCAT(device) as devices FROM file GROUP BY version' file.txt \
    | csvformat -D ':'
version:devices
1.0.0:dev1,dev2
1.2.3:dev3
1.3.4:dev4,dev5
```